# Rails render partial with multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This code is working fine:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :object => @categories = pages , :object => { @myobject => '1', @mmyobject => '2' } %>
```

If I change to this:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :object => { @categories => pages, @myobject => '1', @mmyobject => '2' } %>
```

Then I receive a error from the partial when it try to iterate @categories:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm very new to ruby and rails also, I appreciate any help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

When you pass an `:object` to a Rails partial, a local variable (not an instance variable, beginning with `@`) is defined within the partial which has the same name as the partial. So for the partial `sidebars/_pages.html.erb`, your local variable will be called `pages`.

The value of the `pages` local variable is the Hash you passed as the value of the `:object` option, and none of the instance variables you had in your "outer" view will be available (such as `@categories` or `@myobject`). So you'll need to access those via the `pages` local variable.

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :object => { :categories => @categories, :myobject => '1', :mmyobject => '2' } %>
```

And in `sidebars/_pages.html.erb`, you might have something like this:

```
<p><%= pages[:myobject] %></p>

<ul>
<% pages[:categories].each do |category| %>
  <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

See the Rails Guide to Layouts and Rendering's [Partials section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more details.

**Update:**

An even better solution would be to use the `:locals` option, which accepts a Hash whose keys become local variables with the partial. For instance:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :locals => { :categories => @categories, :myobject => '1', :mmyobject => '2' } %>
```

And in `sidebars/_pages.html.erb`, you might have something like this:

```
<p><%= myobject %></p>
<p><%= mmyobject %></p>

<ul>
<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <li><%= category %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Mr. Stuart, pages is a method from a helper, it only returns Category.all. I am using @categories.each do |c| inside the partials. I'm aware about the best practice of using local variables instead of instance variables, I was just curious why my second line of code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not certain, but your second line of code may not be working because your Hash is setting `@categories => pages`. You probably don't want to have the Hash key be `@categories`, since you won't be accessing it via that key. It should probably be something like `:categories => pages`.

Comment: Mr. Stuart, I double-checked my first line of code and I noticed the `@myobject` and `@mmyobject` are not being passed to the view, since it does not raise any errors I was led to believe it was fine. I apologize for missing this.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code as mentioned above:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :object => @categories = pages , :object => { @myobject => '1', @mmyobject => '2' } %
```

Actually does not raise any errors but also does not pass @myobject and @mmyobject to the view.

Below is the correct* approach for specifying multiple objects with the render method:

```
<%= render 'sidebars/pages', :object => [@categories = pages, @myobject = '2'] %>
```

Like this I can pass multiple objects to the view, without having to define :object more than once.

*at least for my knowledge scope

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what `@categories = pages` is doing: that is setting the instance variable `@categories` to `pages`. Doing that assignment in the `render` statement isn't syntactically invalid, but it doesn't really give you anything. For instance, it does not mean you can access `@categories` within the partial.

Comment: I think you may be best off using the `:locals` option instead of `:object`. You could say `render 'sidebars/pages', :locals => {:categories => @categories, :myobject => '2'}`, and then you would have access to local variables called `categories` and `myobject` within the partial. See the ["Passing Local Variables"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) section of the Rails Guide.

Comment: Yes, I understand sir. I was just trying to figure out how to have instance variables available to a partial coming from a view, since `<%= render 'sidebars/pages' %>` lives inside a view and so far I knew only to pass multiple locals or one object at once from a view to a partial. With my example above I have available @categories in the partial, I double-checked this time. The method pages comes from a helper for testing purposes and is the same as Category.all. I'm testing with Rails 4.

Comment: I'm using `@categories = pages` because I dont want it to be in the controller, if I make it available in the ApplicationController using the before_filter, then it will be requested even when it is not in use.